# How does a miner create a transaction input to spend tx fees?

Tags: transaction-fees, mining-reward

I'm wondering where does a miner get an input for a transaction that spends the tx fees received from mining a block? It's not out of the coinbase transaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transaction fees in a block *are* included in the coinbase transaction, which is a special type of transaction in that it does not have any inputs.

The value of the coinbase transaction’s output can be up to:

`Current block reward + (sum of all inputs in the block - sum of all outputs in the block)`

Claiming more than this will result in the block being invalid, but claiming less than this is allowed (though probably not in the miner’s best interests!)

Comment: Haha I'll gladly eat my words that makes sense, I never noticed before!